# Using a Groupby Object and Resampling in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am hoping to use a groupby and resample on a data frame to get annual counts of a field.  Let's say I had a dataframe structured as such:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'year': {0: '2017', 1: '2018', 2: '2016', 3: '2018'}, 'month': {0: '1', 1: '2', 2: '3', 3: '4'}, 'day': {0: '1', 1: '1', 2: '1', 3: '3'}})
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df)
#Sorry there is probably and easier way to set up the df
df['B']=[1, 2, 3, 1]
df['C']=[2,3,4, 1]
df=df.ix[:, ['Date', 'B', 'C']]

df.groupby('B').resample('A', on='Date')
```

How do I get the last line of code to group by Column B and still be able to resample by year or month, etc?  In the end I'm looking for counts per year of C grouped by B.  I'd like to maintain my index in the process, if possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can groupby column B and date.dt.year

```
df.groupby([df['Date'].dt.year, 'B']).C.count().reset_index()

    Date    B   C
0   2016    3   1
1   2017    1   1
2   2018    1   1
3   2018    2   1
```

Opion 2 using Grouper

```
df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key = 'Date', freq='A'), 'B']).C.count().reset_index()

    Date        B   C
0   2016-12-31  3   1
1   2017-12-31  1   1
2   2018-12-31  1   1
3   2018-12-31  2   1
```

Edit: A round-about way of using resample with groupby, though I don't see why would one use it

```
df.set_index('Date').groupby('B').resample('A').C.count().reset_index()
```

Comment: Fair point.  Just so I know, there is no way to use the pd.resample function?  Thanks.

Comment: @TylerRussell, see edit to use resample with groupby

Comment: That was a helpful way to look at both ways.  Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `resample` but not recommended

```
df.groupby('B').apply(lambda x : x.resample('A', on='Date').C.count())
Out[761]: 
B  Date      
1  2017-12-31    1
   2018-12-31    1
2  2018-12-31    1
3  2016-12-31    1
Name: C, dtype: int64
```